# MySQL query works in phpMyAdmin but not at site. Unknown column 'zone' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

The following query works in phpMyAdmin but doesn't work when I run it in through the website in PHP.

```sql
SELECT * FROM 
      (SELECT name, zone FROM staff 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN zones 
          ON staff.suburb=zones.suburb
      ) A WHERE zone='2'
```

The following query also doesn't work on the website but works in phpMyAdmin:

```sql
SELECT name, zone FROM staff 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN zones 
    ON staff.suburb=zones.suburb 
  WHERE zone='2'
```

Both give an error:

> Unknown column 'zone' in 'where clause'.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure there is column "zone" in the table you're querying? Maybe you made a typo when creating that column?

Comment: Make sure to put the query in "double quotes" in your code... and that you connect to the right database. You could also try `zones.zone` instead of only `zone`.

Comment: phpMyAdmin has a "Export PHP" function, did you use that or copy/paste the query?

Comment: I ccKep I copied and paste the query. It works in phpmyadmin

Comment: I guess you are not connecting to the same database.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run the first query the way you provided, it should be more like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT name,zone 
    FROM staff 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN zones ON staff.suburb=zones.suburb
) A 
WHERE A.zone='2'
```

But I totaly do not understand why you are doing a SUB-SELECT, that is totally unnecessary. The second query should work, unless you have made a typographical error. Also it is good practice to escape every column, or table name used in query, like so:

```
SELECT `name`, `zone` 
FROM `staff` s 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `zones` z 
    ON s.`suburb` = z.`suburb` 
WHERE z.`zone` = '2'
```

Comment: what do you mean by escape every column?

Comment: @user1034912 It means that You enclose every column name or table name in the backquotes... As in mine exmaple above...

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT `name`, `zone`
FROM `staff` AS s
LEFT OUTER JOIN `zones` AS z ON `s`.`suburb`=`z`.`suburb`
WHERE `s`.`zone`='2';
```

Supposing that the column `zone` is in the table `staff`. If it's in the table `zones`, change the WHERE to :

```
WHERE `z`.`zone`='2';
```

The key part here is the precision in the WHERE clause. Maybe MySQL don't know where to look up (in which table), so adding a precision on the table will reduce the risk. Moreover, make sur this column exists in that table (and with that typo. `zones` or `Zone` could lead to errors).